# Simple c# exercise for beginners. I'm stuck

Tags: c#

i'm doing an exercise in c# to practice but i'm not clearly sure what and how i'm supposed to do things. (i'm not thinking as a compiler yet) :( .

**The exercise is set like this.**

- We have two children, a and b, and the parameters aSmile and bSmile
  indicate if each is smiling.
- We are in trouble if they are both smiling or if neither of them is
  smiling.
- Return true if we are in trouble.
- AreWeInTrouble(true, true) -> true
- AreWeInTrouble(false, false) -> true
- AreWeInTrouble(true, false) -> false

public bool AreWeInTrouble(bool aSmile, bool bSmile) 
{}

**My code until now:**

```
public bool AreWeInTrouble(bool aSmile, bool bSmile)
    {

        if (aSmile == true && bSmile == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (aSmile == false && bSmile == false)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
```

I have put put this method in the main method in Program.cs  so once the program starts the method gets called.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AreWeInTrouble(aSmile, bSmile);
    }
```

But when i call this method i get an error that a and b Smile do not exist in the current content.

So id like to ask if someone can give me some hints/tips for solving this exercise.
I'm not sure how to proceed from here but id like to understand what is missing and retry it.

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: At the minute, `aSmile` and `bSmile` are parameters to a method, that method requires some variables passing in...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but just as a hint you do not need the "== true" either. aSmile and bSmile are already booleans, so you can just do "if (aSmile && bSmile)" and "if (!aSmile && !bSmile)"

Comment: Also, I think you should take a look at your boolean algebra lessons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or Just `return !(aSmile ^ bSmile);`

Comment: Although `!(aSmile ^ bSmile)` being logically correct, `aSmile == bSmile` is the best implementation for `AreWeInTrouble`.

Comment: The MSDN entry about [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173114.aspx) (especially Method Parameters VS. Arguments) might be of interest. -- "The method definition specifies the names and types of any parameters that are required. When calling code calls the method, it provides concrete values called arguments for each parameter."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass in some values, since `aSmile` and `bSmile` aren't know variables in that method.

From example:

```
 AreWeInTrouble(true, false);
```

Second, you should catch the return value:

```
 bool result = AreWeInTrouble(true, false);
```

And possibly display it:

```
 bool result = AreWeInTrouble(true, false);
 Console.WriteLine("Are we in trouble? {0}", result);
```

Also, make your method `static` since the `Main` method is:

```
public static bool AreWeInTrouble(bool aSmile, bool bSmile)
{ }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  AreWeInTrouble(true, false); was previously red underlined (before i add static  to the method). Any method that goes into the static void main needs to be static too ? I didn't learn using the static keyword in the methods yet. I'll check it out, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(AreWeInTrouble(true, true));   // In trouble
    Console.WriteLine(AreWeInTrouble(false, false)); // In trouble
    Console.WriteLine(AreWeInTrouble(true, false));  // Not in trouble

    Console.ReadLine(true);
}

static bool AreWeInTrouble(bool aSmile, bool bSmile) {
    // If aSmile matches bSmile then we are in trouble.
    return aSmile == bSmile;
}
```

Comment: I say  `return !(aSmile ^ bSmile);` and I don't see the equality test. Was riveted!

Answer (score 1):

The `AreWeInTrouble` method looks fine (but as a hint: have a look at the exclusive or operator, XOR).

The call in the main method refers to variables, which aren't defined in the scope of the `Main` method.

```
public static void Main()
{
    AreWeInTrouble(aSmile, bSmile); // <--- aSmile, bSmile are not defined
}
```

You can call the method with the boolean constants `true` and `false` or you'll need to define the variables in the scope of the main method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool aSmile = true;
    bool bSmile = false;
    AreWeInTrouble(aSmile, bSmile); // returns false
    AreWeInTrouble(aSmile, true); // returns true
}
```

And of course, the `AreWeInTrouble`method must be declared as `static`as the `Main` method is static and therefore has no access to instance methods of the class without having an instance.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest to you is to create a unit test for this method, so you can put the inputs you want and what is expected from the return. This will make you a better coder for more sophisticated scenarios. [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs.aspx)

About the boolean solving, think with me you want something like this:

```
bool areBothSmilling = aSmile && bSmile; // Booleans don`t need ==, the == will return a boolean;
bool areBothNotSmilling = !aSmile && bSmile == false; // ! and == false will produce the same results
return areBothSmilling || areBothNotSmilling;
```

But if you think more carefully, you want to return true if the two booleans are equal, so I think this solves it too:

```
return aSmile == bSmile;
```

Comment: I removed the (condescending) commentary from your post... I also don't think this addresses the actual issue the OP was having.

Comment: Now I see the last line of his question is questionating why doesn`t compile, but no worries, this answer can stay to help him to try to understand the boolean operators better

Answer (score 0):

you shoud just declare aSmile and bSmile like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool aSmile=true;
    bool bSmile=false;
    AreWeInTrouble(aSmile, bSmile);
}
```

and your method should have this signature

```
public static bool  AreWeInTrouble(bool aSmile,bool bSmile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic can be implemented by simple XNOR logic.

```
public static bool AreWeInTrouble(bool aSmile, bool bSmile)
{
    return aSmile == bSmile;
}
```